# R: fitting of a contour/complex shape to a model (multiple Y, single X)

Tags: r, optimization, parameters, shapes, contour

I'm using a model to fit complex leaf shape patterns to data. The data are just contour coordinates from (half) leaf scans which can look anything from a normal function to a complex shape, with multiple Y coordinates for the same X (for example think of one side of a maple leaf).

The model however, does not provide a function, but rather a generated sequence of coordinates according to a specific set of rules. These coordinates are not a pairwise approximation of the data (i.e. the points calculated from the model do not have the same intervals as the data, see image below)
The point of the exercise if to find a function to minimize (like you would use residual sum of squares for a simple shape) so that the parameters of my model could be optimized to describe the shape as accurately as possible.

Example 1: a simple shape, single Y for single X. In the image shown below:[image: simple shape]

The black dots are the datapoints while the red ones are the model generated points for an optimal fit. As you can see the 2 datasets do not have equal intervals so I used an interpolation method to calculate the RSS of the model on a set of control points (for example, interpolating both datasets for a number of points along the axis). This provides me with an optimal fit, so no problems here.

Example 2: a complex shape, multiple y, single x. A possibility of a shape generated by the model is the following: [image: complex shape]

Assuming I have a dataset describing a shape this model generation approximates. How can I go about determining how well the model fits my contour?

Comment: Try narrowing down the question to a specific programming question. As the question stands, it's very broad and non-specific.

Comment: I added some examples per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever comes across a similar problem. I eventually solved it by working with an area overlap optimization. Using the r packages sp and rgeos.

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
PolysData <- Polygons(list(Polygon(contourData), "Poly")
SpPData <- SpatialPolygons(list(PolysData), 1:1)
ParamOpt <- function(par){
    RSS <- tryCatch({
      contourGen <- GenerateShape(par)
      PolyFit <-  Polygon(contourGen)
      PolysFit <- Polygons(list(PolyFit), "Poly")
      SpPFit <- SpatialPolygons(list(PolysFit), 1:1)
      RSS <- tryCatch({
        Inters <- gIntersection(SpPData,SpPFit)
        TruePos <- Inters@polygons[[1]]@area
        FalsePos <- SpPFit@polygons[[1]]@area-TruePos
        FalseNeg <- SpPData@polygons[[1]]@area-TruePos
        TrueNeg <- 1-TruePos-FalsePos-FalseNeg
        Acc <- (TruePos+TrueNeg)/(TruePos+TrueNeg+FalsePos+FalseNeg)
        return(1 - Acc)
      }, error = function(err) {
        RSS <- 10
        return(RSS)
      })
      return(RSS)
    }, error = function(err) {
      RSS <- 10
      return(RSS)
    })
    return(RSS)
}
```

the GenerateShape function is a self written function creating shapes as presented in the question based on parameters. The criterion is based on the evaluation criteria from "Image processing techniques and segmentation evaluation" (Smochina, 2011)